# Play DVD with VLC from USB device

Tags: arch-linux, usb-drive, vlc, dvd

I've installed the media player [vlc](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) and added the current user to the `optical` group.

```
# sudo pacman -S vlc qt4
# sudo gpasswd -a <my_user> optical
```

Afterwards I restarted my computer and plugged the USB DVD device inluding a DVD into the computer. I found the device at `/dev/sr0` and mounted it manually to `/mnt/dvd`.

```
# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 119,2G  0 disk 
...
sr0     11:0    1   6,3G  0 rom  /mnt/dvd
```

Then I opened the VLC player GUI and selected the device. When I close the dailog with pressing play, then I hear the USB device starting. But after a couple of seconds it stops and nothing happens anymore. There is no error message or something else.

How can I play the DVD from USB device?

Comment: Have you checked if the usb drive is correctly mounted, you can see the content of the DVD ? What `lsusb` says about the DVD device ? Can you play the DVD using root credentials ?

Comment: It's mounted correctly, I guess. `ls /mnt/dvd/` shows the directories `AUDIO_TS` and `VIDEO_TS`. `lsusb` shows the DVD device, `Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0e8d:1806 MediaTek Inc. Samsung SE-208 Slim Portable DVD Writer`. I didn't know this command. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, which was also described in the [ArchWiki](http://go2linux.garron.me/play-protectec-css-cd-dvd-linux/).

While the packages `libdvdread` and `libdvdnav` are dependencies of the package `vlc`, the package `libdvdcss` was missing. The vlc player gave me no hint, but after installing the package, I can view the movie.

```
sudo pacman -S libdvdcss
```

Afterwards I found a [blog post](http://go2linux.garron.me/play-protectec-css-cd-dvd-linux/), which mentions the error message "Media stream scrambled/encrypted". I could'nt find any error message.